# how to implement tilt.js jquery destroy method inside another function

Tags: jquery, tilt

Here below I'm trying to insert the tilt destroy method for jquery but I can't do it...

It's not clear for me this line of code that I get on the official website

```
(const tilt = $('.js-tilt').tilt()
tilt.methods.destroy.call(tilt);)
```

can you help, please?

```
$( function() {

    //start titl  
    const tilt = $('.items').tilt({scale: 1.2});

    $( ".items1" ).draggable({ revert: true },{ 
        start: function() {

          // i dont know how to destroy or disable titl.js on start
        },
        drag: function() {

         // items.tilt.destroy.call(items);
         // i dont know how to destroy or disable titl.js on drag
        },
        stop: function() {

            $(".about").show();

           // if destroy method wors probably i need to re-enable it
           // restart titl when drag is finished 
           const tilt = $('.items').tilt({scale: 1.2});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Within your `start:` add: `tilt.methods.destroy.call(tilt)` you already have the variable.

Comment: Hi thanks
done but the problem now is that the drag event not work

      start: function() {
       

tilt.methods.destroy.call(tilt)
      },
probably I'm missing something..